# How to find Employee Availability overlap where end date is null

Tags: mysql

I have employee availability table with following fields

```
id | user_id | day_of_week | start_date | end_date
```

Where `end_date` could be `null`.

When user updates their availability I want to check if it overlaps with any of the current data and update or delete those overlaps.

New availability supplied by the user could also be without `end_date`.

How can I find a an overlap where `end_date` can be null?

I have tried following query but it doesn't return accurate result because of `null` field.

If a user has following availability

```
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
|  1 |       3 |           1 | 2021-04-12 | 2021-05-17 |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
|  2 |       3 |           1 | 2021-05-24 | 2021-07-19 |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
|  3 |       3 |           1 | 2021-07-26 | 2021-08-16 |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
|  4 |       3 |           1 | 2021-08-23 | NULL       |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

Now if user wants to insert new availability for `2021-03-05` to `2021-08-02`, it will overlap with first 3 rows which I can get using following query.

```
select
  *
from
  `availabilities`
where `user_id` = 3
  AND '2021-03-05' < end_date
  AND '2021-08-02' > start_date
```

But when I change the `end_date` to `2021-08-30` it should add 4th row as well but since the `end_date` of that row is empty, results is still the same.

I have also tried following query but result is not accurate

```
select
  *
from
  `availabilities`
where `user_id` = 2
  and `start_date` <= '2021-08-30'
  and (
    `end_date` >= '2021-03-05'
    or `end_date` is null
  )
```

I have also tried following query

```
SELECT * FROM availabilities
WHERE start_date between '2021-05-17' and '2021-08-30';
```

But it does not work since the above query should return `row 1` as well because new shift will overlap first row.

Another scenario is when user gives their availability with only `start_date` and no `end_date`. How can I check for overlaps in those cases?

Here is [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aac05b/2)

when user supplied `start_date` = `2021-03-05` and `end_date` = `2021-08-02` or
`start_date` = `2021-05-17` and `end_date` = `2021-08-16` result should be as follow

```
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
|  1 |       3 |           1 | 2021-04-12 | 2021-05-17 |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
|  2 |       3 |           1 | 2021-05-24 | 2021-07-19 |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
|  3 |       3 |           1 | 2021-07-26 | 2021-08-16 |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

when user supplied `start_date` = `2021-03-05` and no `end_date` result should be as follow

```
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
|  1 |       3 |           1 | 2021-04-12 | 2021-05-17 |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
|  2 |       3 |           1 | 2021-05-24 | 2021-07-19 |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
|  3 |       3 |           1 | 2021-07-26 | 2021-08-16 |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
|  4 |       3 |           1 | 2021-08-23 | NULL       |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

Thank you

Comment: your 'not accurate' query has its start_date and end_date constants transposed. [transposing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aac05b/18) them returns the last row.

Answer (score 1):

To overlap your new entry, and existing entry must both:

1. Start before the new entry ends UNLESS the new entry never ends
2. End after the new entry starts UNLESS the existing entry never ends

I'm pseudocoding an example that would work below; you don't mention a language, so be sure to use whatever escaping mechanism your language provides:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM availabilities
WHERE ($end_date IS NULL OR start_date < $end_date)
AND (end_date > $start_date OR end_date IS NULL);
```

Comment: I did not understand the Part 1 and Part 2 that you described above, can you please provide and example with date so I can work on part 2.

Comment: My mistake. The example I've given will solve both parts. I've edited the confusing bit out. If you want to understand the overlap logic, start by ignoring the "end date is null" stuff and consider how you'd tell if two entries *DID NOT* overlap. Once you have that logic you can invert it to find if you have an overlap.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is helpful :

```
    SELECT * FROM availabilities
WHERE start_date between '2021-03-05' and '2021-08-30';
```

Comment: that's why I use 'start_date' , or I think i don't understand your question  yet.

Comment: I have updated the question to include your query but it does not return correct results.

Comment: can you add table format of your require result in question?

Comment: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aac05b/12) here u have result

Comment: It works only if user has supplied `start_date` and `end_date`, what if I only have `start_date`

Comment: if user not supplied any end date then use current_month end date or any date above last start_date

Comment: according to @Simon Brahan answer [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aac05b/24)

Answer (score 0):

If endDate is null, why not make the result("XXXX-XX-XX" < end_date) be true directly.
Maybe like: `'and ((XXXX-XX-XX' < end_date) or (end_date is null))`.

Comment: The format of this site favours complete answers in one post rather than a discussion. Can you edit your post to include your complete answer, rather than breaking it into comments?

Comment: I think It's similar to the second query in my question, which does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM availabilities
WHERE "2021-03-05" < COALESCE(end_date,start_date)
  AND "2021-08-30" > start_date
;
```